# How to get the records from the table correctly? Python, sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can you *correctly* get records from a table using a declarative base?

I have a database that consists of tables called `guild_%number%`, which has the following columns: `id`, `description`, `sex`, `age`.

Ultimately, I want to get something like this:

```py
async def get_user(guild_id: int, user_id: int):
    class User(Base):
        # ...

    __return__= User
    return User

user= await get_user(12345, 123)
print(user.description)
user.description="Hello"
print(user.description)
```

Comment: You definitely do not want to define model classes inside functions. That's not how SQLAlchemy works. [I suggest you start with basic tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sqlalchemy%20tutorials) because StackOverflow Q&A format is not good for basic education.